# While dynamically populating Bootstrap Gridview, one of the row value is not returning the Outer HTML

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

Javascript

```
function FormatFileCategory(value, row) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var ret = "";
        var urlService = VirtualPathUtility + "api/Fleet/Vehicles/VehicleDetails/AttachmentCategoryList/";

    fetch(urlService)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error("Error retrieving attachment categories.");
            }
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            var selectElement = document.createElement("select");

            var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
            optionElement.value = "0";
            optionElement.innerText = "Please Select";
            selectElement.appendChild(optionElement);

            data.forEach(function (value) {
                optionElement = document.createElement("option");
                optionElement.value = value.Id;
                optionElement.innerText = value.CatName;
                selectElement.appendChild(optionElement);
            });
            debugger;
            ret = selectElement.outerHTML;
            resolve(ret);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            SendMessage("Vehicles", "populateAttachmentCAT: " + error.message, HiddenContactId.val());
            reject(error);


         });
    });
}

async function handleFormatFileCategory(value,row) {
    try {
        
        const ret = await FormatFileCategory(value, row);        
        return ret;
    } catch (error) {

    // Handle the error here
    console.error(error);


   }
   
}
```

ASPX

```
<table id="attachmentTable"
                                class="table-condensed table-striped mGrid"
                                data-toggle="table"
                                data-search="false"
                                data-sort-name="Id"
                                data-sort-order="asc"
                                data-show-columns="false"
                                data-advanced-search="false"
                                data-id-table="advancedTable"
                                data-show-multi-sort="false"
                                data-show-export="false"
                                data-toolbar="#toolbar"
                                data-click-to-select="false"
                                data-cookie="false"
                                data-pagination="true"
                                data-show-jump-to="false"
                                data-url="api/Fleet/Vehicles/VehicleDetails/AttachmentList/<%=Hidden_VehicleId.Value %>/"
                                data-cookie-id-table=""
                                data-page-size="10"
                                data-page-list="[10, 25, 500, 1000, 10000, All]"
                                data-custom-view="attachmentCardViewFormatter"
                                data-show-custom-view="false">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th data-field="Id" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true">ID</th>
                                        <th data-field="FileName" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">File Name</th>
                                        <th data-field="Id" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-formatter="attachmentTableImageFormatter">Image</th>
                                       
                                        <th data-field="IsMainString" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true">Is Main</th>
                                        <th data-field="FileCategory" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-formatter="handleFormatFileCategory">Category</th>
                                        <th data-field="IsPrivate" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-formatter="FormatPrivateCategory">Is Private</th>

                                        <th data-field="Id" data-searchable="true" data-formatter="AttachmentHistoryEditFormatter">Edit</th>
                                        <th data-field="Id" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-formatter="attachmentTableDeleteFormatter">Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
```

handleFormatFileCategory function is returning [object Promise] as result. THanks